# Jmeter response time is very high for cached request which retrieves 124 embedded resources from cache as compared with browser

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter is giving very high response time(12 seconds) for the request which retrieves 124 cached embedded requests from jmeter http cache manager (Jmeter is cached 120 requests--304 response code and 4 request not cached--200 response code), even http cache manager cache 120 requests why it's giving more response time it's not matching to browser.When browser downloading 124 request it takes 2 to 3 seconds retrieves from memory/disk cache. How can i simulate the same response time in jmeter.

Please see the screen shot jmeter and browser response times in below drive link
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NnGD3dPgmDn60W6CZ534KkU-x2E76Dwy?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) will return embedded resources (images, scripts, styles, etc.) from cache starting from **2nd request**, for the first request for each virtual user/iteration you will always get full content.

If you're comparing the first request make sure to tick `Disable cache` box in browser developer tools:

[image]

You might also want to inspect [request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) and ensure that JMeter sends exactly the same headers via [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), for example [Accept-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) header can greatly reduce response time due to requesting compressed content from the endpoint.

More information: [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your reply,but my question is not for first request which gets full content, same user second request which has similar content plus other request. similar request will giving me more response time even http cache manager cache the data from first request, but browser gives very less response time for second request which has similar content..please see the screen shot attached for both, response times are not matched in jmeter,why second request content giving more response time even with it's cached by http cache manager...cached content giving 304 response code in embedded

Comment: Please check jmx attached in below location, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xht3fV8HcugjLKbbKT-S3jLiEgsdb-jF/view?usp=sharing